# Excel VBA - Loop needed for a column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm very new to excel VBA and I can't figure out how to get this to work.  I have a column (column K), with a header in K1.  I get this spreadsheet every day and it has a different number of rows.  Column K has numbers from 0-100.  I need to highlight certain rows certain colors depending on the value in column K.  This is what I have so far, but it just goes all the way down and makes every column red font.  I need it to loop through k2 to the last K cell with a value and change the font color of each row.

```
Columns("K").Select
Dim firstCell As Integer
Dim finalCell As Integer
firstCell = Range("K2")
finalCell = Range("K65536").End(xlUp).Row
For i = firstCell To finalCell

If i > 5 Then
    Rows(i).Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End With
ElseIf i = 4 Then
    Rows(i).Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Color = RGB(226, 107, 10)
    End With
ElseIf i = 3 Then
    Rows(i).Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
    End With
ElseIf i = 2 Then
    Rows(i).Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Color = RGB(0, 112, 192)
    End With
ElseIf i = 1 Then
    Rows(i).Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Color = RGB(112, 48, 160)
    End With
End If
Next i
```

Comment: Two Links to get you started. [FIRST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) and [SECOND](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Comment: BTW you can also use Autofilter to color the cells. You don't need to loop through all 100 or so cells

Comment: In this using "Case" will easy to write the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your if statements you're just referencing i, not the value contained in Column K and Row i which is what you seem to want.

So change the if statements from:

```
If i > 5 Then
'and
ElseIf i = 4 Then
```

to:

```
If Range("K" & i).Value > 5 Then
'and
ElseIf Range("K" & i).Value = 4 Then
```

For all your if statements. Also change your first and final cell statements. They might, work, but I know these will:

```
finalCell = ActiveSheet.Range("K" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'and 
firstCell = 2
```

Comment: + 1 For clarifying what is the error in the code :) However... `finalCell = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count` Nooooooo :) Please never do that :) See the first link I gave below the question.

Comment: Thank you, I'll update my code. That statement always worked well for me, I'll definitely use that for the rest of my time!

Comment: Wow, thanks a ton.  I switched this info in and works perfectly.  Thanks to both of you for the links, code, and time.  I already learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Since the two links which I mentioned in the comment do not cover about auto filter, see this example. Also What if the number is `5`? Your code doesn't handle that. Did you by any chance mean ">4"? If yes, then change ">5" to ">4" in the code below.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        lRow = .Range("K" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        With .Range("K1:K" & lRow)
            For i = 1 To 4
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & i

                Set rng = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow

                If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                    Select Case i
                        Case 1: rng.Font.Color = RGB(112, 48, 160)
                        Case 2: rng.Font.Color = RGB(0, 112, 192)
                        Case 3: rng.Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
                        Case 4: rng.Font.Color = RGB(226, 107, 10)
                    End Select

                    Set rng = Nothing
                End If

                ws.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
            Next i

            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">5" '<~~ OR "<4" ???
            Set rng = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End With

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: After I ran the working macro the first time I realized I forgot about if it equals 5.  Thanks!  I have updated this as well and all lines formatted exactly as I had hoped.  Thanks for help!!

Comment: You are welcome. One more tip before you go :) Whenever you are declaring variables which will hold the rows, never declare it as `Integer`. Declare it as a `Long` else you may get `Overflow` error in xl2007+ if you are working with bigger number of rows...